# Fire Javascript event when game is completed

Tags: javascript, flash

My question:

I have a Flash game. It has 15 questions in it. Each question answered correct gives you one coin. There's a function in the game that updates the coins and experience: `function updatePointsAndCoins_V2()`.

http://www.squlaworld.com/demo-english

- I'm working on an overlay that is displayed when the 15th coin is received.

I have created an overlay in a folder with CSS, HTML and JS-files. Is there a way to load these files when the `function updatePointsAndCoins_V2()` gives off `value = 15`?

- Another possibility is:
  I already have a default endscreen in the game. When the game is completed it starts a function: `function suggestedQuiz()`. 
  Is there a way to load the overlay-files when that function is started?

This is the overlay script i'm using:

```
(function(showOverlay) {
    var triggerBttn = document.getElementById( 'trigger-overlay' ),
        overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
        closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
        transEndEventNames = {
            'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
            'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
            'msTransition': 'MSTransitionEnd',
            'transition': 'transitionend'
        },
        transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
        support = { transitions : Modernizr.csstransitions };

    function toggleOverlay() {
        if( classie.has( overlay, 'open' ) ) {
            var wrapperposition = document.getElementById('wrapperposition');
            wrapperposition.style.display = 'none';

            classie.remove( overlay, 'open' );
            classie.add( overlay, 'close' );
            var onEndTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
                if( support.transitions ) {
                    if( ev.propertyName !== 'visibility' ) return;
                    this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
                }
                classie.remove( overlay, 'close' );
            };
            if( support.transitions ) {
                overlay.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndTransitionFn );
            }
            else {
                onEndTransitionFn();
            }
        }
        else if( !classie.has( overlay, 'close' ) ) {
            classie.add( overlay, 'open' );
            var wrapperposition = document.getElementById('wrapperposition');
            wrapperposition.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }

    triggerBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
    closeBttn.addEventListener( 'click', toggleOverlay );
})();
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean flash?

Comment: The game is made in Flash. Here's the link to the game:http://www.squlaworld.com/demo-english

Comment: That is most certainly flash. Probably worth tagging the post with "flash" as people who are most qualified to answer this will be flash developers rather than javascript developers.

Comment: Good point, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your page you will need to define the method which the flash game is attempting to invoke. In this case it is the updatePointsAndCoins_V2 method.

So, in your page you can add something like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-js --> // ignore this line, it's for stackoverflow syntax highlighting
<script>
    function updatePointsAndCoins_V2 (coins) {
        console.log(coins); //look in the console to see what coins is
        // With nothing to go on I'll assume it passes them as a number in the first parameter of the function
        if (coins >= 15) {
             showOverlay(); // You will need to define this function and the logic which shows your overlay.
        } 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid javascript to me. What are you expecting that code to do? It seems to me that you want to check the coin count in the flash application, if it is 15, use the above approaches to trigger your javascript function, the javascript will show an overlay.

Comment: I can't make any changes to the Flash game, because that is loaded in a container. The only thing I can do is listen for the these functions and start the overlay when the value is 15.

Comment: Ah ok, if you are unable to modify the flash then you have a slightly different problem. Unless the flash application specifically triggers a javascript function you have no way of listening to those events, unless I'm mistaken. I was working on the assumption that you had access to the games source.

Comment: I completely get that assumption, I didn't specify that clear enough in my question. The game triggers a javascript function each time a coin is received. That value is stored inside an array. The functions that are being triggered are: updatePointsAndCoins_V2 and suggestedQuiz.

Comment: Ah ok! That makes more sense. I'll update my answer for you.

Comment: You're amazing, it's a shame I can't up vote you yet! I've updated my question with the overlay script. Did I define the showOverlay in a proper way?

Comment: Mostly looks ok, the main thing is that you have defined a self invoking function and defined a parameter called showOverlay instead of a named function with that name. What will happen is it will execute as soon as the script loads rather than when your flash application invokes the updatePointsAndCoins_V2 method. If you have created a updatePointsAndCoins_V2 method which invokes showOverlay() you will get an undefined error. However if it calls toggleOverlay, you can remove the showOverlay parameter and it should be good. Hope that made sense! Main thing, does it work? :)